# How do I access urls in an excel file and scrape information stored in those links using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access a set of urls present in rows and scrape respective information from all those links and store it in a text file. I have my links stored in a file - **"ctp_output.csv"**
Currently I am able to extract information by directly providing a single link. Require some guidance.

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.thedrum.com/news/2015/07/29/mankind-must-get-ahead-technical-development-states-phds-mark-holden-following"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
with open('ctp_output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for tag in soup.find_all('p'):
        f.write(tag.text.encode('utf-8') + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next step is to open the csv file and then loop over each line, extracting information for each link. You can do that like this:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        url = line[0] # assuming your url is your first column
        .... # scraping code here
```

Comment: it should be `with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:`

Comment: @RahulChawla Thanks. I'm used to python3 syntax.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  Only the information of the url present in the last row is scraped.

Comment: @RRR And I know why. That's because you keep opening the file in write mode, so you erase the contents each time you overwrite. That's for you to handle. But this works. ;)

Comment: @RRR You can't keep opening the file in write mode. Because each time you do that, the file contents are cleared. You will need to open it in 'a' append mode. `open('ctp_output.txt', 'a')`. You need to go to your file directory and create an empty file called `ctp_output.txt`. Then run this program. Also, if this answer helped, please consider marking it accepted.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks. Though I created an empty .txt file and opened using append mode, I face the same problem. Am I going wrong in the csv file that I am reading from? It is initially written using 'w' mode.

Comment: @RRR I don't think that's it. Maybe you don't need to create the file externally... Hmm...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes, I don't need to create a new file. When I initially write into the csv file, i use "wb+" mode. And before reading the file, i use f.seek(0) so that the pointer goes back to the first location. with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f: f.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        url = line[0]     - I still encounter the same problem. Only the last link is read.

Comment: Oh. That's it. If you use `wb+`, you don't need to externally do it. The `+` handles is for you. Awesome.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Still doesn't work :( Sorry for the trouble :(

Comment: @RRR Remove the `b`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use import the csv in `pandas` dataframe using `pandas.read_csv()`.
Then iterate through the rows of the dataframe like

```
for url in data_frame_name.iterrows():
....use the url to get the information like you did in the question.
```

Comment: data_frame_name is the name if the data frame in which you stored the csv contents using read_csv(). For example, df1 = pandas.read_csv(location of the file). Here data_frame_name is df1.

Comment: The file doesn't get initialized.